# What is the purpose of : * and classOf in Scala?

Tags: scala

For example when I need to running javaFX application with scala, i must to typed a code like this:

```
object ChangeCurrentFrame{

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    Application.launch( classOf[ChangeCurrentFrame ], args: _*)
  }
}
```

I dont really understand what is the meaning of `args : _ *` in that snippet.